# how can i add weight in adjacency list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I want to add weight to the adjacency list. My code is given below for the graph.

```
 graph = defaultdict(list) 
 U,V = map(int,input().split()) 
 for i in range(V):
     u,v = map(str,input().split())
     graph[u].append(v)
     graph[v].append(u)
```

I want to add pair to the list, but I don't know how to do it. I am new to python.
I want to take input like:
A B 6 where B is the destination and 6 is the cost

Comment: Please provide some input data and the expected output in a reproducible way.

Comment: A - > B ->  6 ,, where B is the destination and 6 is the cost

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use 
List of list of list in python
ArrayList of ArrayList of 2-size ArrayList(for node and weight) in java

0-->[[Node1_connected_with_0,weight],[Node2_connected_with_0,weight],...]

1-->[[Node1_connected_with_1,weight],[Node2_connected_with_1,weight],...]

2-->[[Node1_connected_with_2,weight],[Node2_connected_with_2,weight4],...]

.

.
.

[[[N1,w1],[N2,W2],....],[[N3,w3],[N4,w4]]....]



Here if you will see image its something like this in program.

[

[[3,6],[4,3]],

[[1,3]],

[[4,2]],

[[2,1],[3,1]],

[[2,4],[4,2]]

]
```

considering array index starting from 1

```
Node 1 is connected with node 3 and 4 with weight 6 and 3 respectively

Node 2 is connected with node 1 with weight  3 

Node 3 is connected with node 4 with weight 2

and so on
```

[image]